# Calling webpack.ignorePlugin (to tree-shake Moment.js locales) with CRA + rescripts

Tags: webpack, create-react-app, tree-shaking, react-app-rewired, webpack-config

I am using CRA + with [rescripts](https://github.com/harrysolovay/rescripts)

I want to tree-shake Moment.js locales, exactly the same way as shown in [ignorePlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/ignore-plugin/#root) Webpack docs:

```
new webpack.IgnorePlugin({
  checkResource (resource) {
    // do something with resource
    return true|false;
  }
});
```

I know I can easily transform webpack config with a rescript:

```
config => {
   const newConig = ...
   return newConfig
}
```

But how can I get hold of the `webpack` object to call the `IgnorePlugin` method - or achieve the same result?

I am willing to switch from rescripts to an alternative, like `react-app-rewired`, if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

The resulting configuration should have, among other options, a `plugins` options.

So let's say that your `newConfig` inherits all the `config` options. Normally the `newConfig.plugins` will point to the inherited default plugin's array.

To enhance/extend the plugins list all you have to do is to alter that array, ie. just push your plugin at whatever index (eg. last) within that `newConfig.plugins` array.

Example:

```
const Webpack = require("webpack");

function webpack(config, env) {
  const newConfig = Object.assign({}, config);
  newConfig.plugins = newConfig.plugins || [];

  const myPlugin = new Webpack.IgnorePlugin({
    checkResource(resource) {
      // do something with resource
      return true | false;
    }
  });

  newConfig.plugins.push(myPlugin);

  return newConfig;
}

module.exports = { webpack };
```