How to configure webpack to exclude certain modules from a library?
I have a React app that imports a library (in the node_modules directory, of course).
The name of the library is @lib/schema.
In the react app, modules of this library are imported like so:
import { module_name } from "@lib/schema"

There is a certain file in the @lib/schema that is currently being included in the final bundle, which is located in this path:
src/path/to/large_file.js

The file is never used by the app and thus unnecessarily increases the size of the bundle.
The React app currently uses react-scripts to create the bundle.
Questions:

If the React app were to continue to use react-scripts, how do I configure it to exclude src/path/to/large_file.js?
If the React app were to use webpack, how do I configure it to exclude src/path/to/large_file.js?


react-scripts aka CRA uses webpack. If large_file isn't used in the app, it's not supposed to be end up in a bundle. It's unknown if "unnecessarily increases the size of the bundle" is true and why is this so

@EstusFlask There is a line of code in the library like so, require(src/path/to/${file_name}). I believe this line of code is what is causing the large_file.js to be included even when it is not used.

I see. The easiest way to avoid this is to structure a project in a way unwanted file won't be matched by dynamic import, i.e. "to" contains only files in use. You can also use webpack plugins like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64489518 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79022172 , you'll need react-app-rewired or craco to change wp config in cra. Or you can try webpackExclude https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#magic-comments

@EstusFlask can you write up an answer, if possible? Thanks

If you want to completely avoid importing the file, you can create an alias for it that points to an empty module.
1.Modify your Webpack configuration:
In your webpack.config.js, add an alias for the large file:
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
// ... other configurations
resolve: {
alias: {
  '@lib/schema/src/path/to/large_file.js': path.resolve(__dirname, 
'path/to/empty.js'),
},
},
};

2.Create an empty module:
Create a file named empty.js in the specified path (e.g., path/to/empty.js)
Conclusion
By following the above methods, you can effectively exclude src/path/to/large_file.js from your final bundle, whether you are using react-scripts or a custom Webpack configuration. Choose the method that best fits your project's setup.

react-scripts belongs to CRA, which uses Webpack.
If large_file isn't used in the app, it's not supposed to be in a bundle. For a dynamic import like require(`src/path/to/${file_name}`) all files inside to/ are included to a bundle.
The easiest way to avoid this is to structure a project in a way unwanted file won't be matched by dynamic import, i.e. to/ contains only the files in use.
It's possible to change CRA's Webpack config with tools like react-app-rewired or Craco. Webpack IgnorePlugin or ContextReplacementPlugin can be used to exclude a module when it's already included.
Alternatively, webpackExclude option can be used in a comment to annotate an import.
